# Kafka consumer group clean up

Tags: apache-kafka

I was testing a Kafka streaming application. It’s possible that the app may have exited uncleanly at some point during testing, and now I have some consumer group data that I am unable to get rid of.

If I try...

```
Kafka-consumer-groups —group testgrp —delete
```

...it gives the following error:

```
Error: Deletion of some consumer groups failed:
Group ‘testgrp’ could not be deleted due to: java.util.ExecutionException: .org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupNotException: The group is not empty
```

Resetting offsets gives another error stating:

```
Assignments can only be reset if the group is  inactive , but the current state is Stable.
```

When I describe the state it does show the state is Stable, but I have confirmed the client app has exited and there are no zombie process running.

Is there a way to clean up the consumer group member information and state without deleting all the meta data of the broker/zookeeper?

Comment: restarting the broker should do it

Comment: Groups are automatically removed after a week, by default